# Android rotation: Why fragment not restored by TAG?

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-rotation, onrestoreinstancestate

I have an activity called MainActivity with a fragment inside called 'HomeFragment'. I want to restore fragment after screen rotation, however something seems missing.
I followed below process:

1. save fragment by using `getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(...)` during `onSaveInstanceState`
2. try to restore fragment by `fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag` during onCreate (after checking that bundle is not null)

However `findFragmentByTag` returns null.

Here is code snippets inside MainActivity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar to show a dropdown list.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        setupNavigationSpinner(actionBar);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("frag") != null) { 
                //  findFragmentByTag always return null
                homeFragment = (HomeFragment) fragmentManager
                        .findFragmentByTag(HomeFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
                contentFragment = homeFragment;
            }else{
                homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                switchContent(homeFragment, HomeFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
            }
        } else {
            homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            switchContent(homeFragment, HomeFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
        }

}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "frag",homeFragment );
}

public void switchContent(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    while (fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate())
        ;

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag);
        // Only ArticlDetailFragment is added to the back stack.
        if (!(fragment instanceof Fragment)) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
        }
        transaction.commit();
        contentFragment = fragment;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was having this same issue for some reason.

Comment: Uh... you might want to show us what's happening in `switchContent`.

Comment: Is `HomeFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID` equal to `"frag"`? Why are you checking for `"frag"`? As I see, you are replacing your fragment with `HomeFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to call

```
getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "frag",homeFragment );
```

A `Fragment` state will automatically be restored. The problem is that you're not calling the super of your `onSaveInstanceState`. It should simply look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Also, you're setting the tag as `HomeFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID` then looking for `"frag"`. Does `HomeFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID == "frag"`?

Comment: I just changed the keys to "FRAG" to check out probable errors, however main problem, as you noticed was about calling `    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);`